# Как я могу добыть данные с google docs с помощью python

Tags: python, google-docs

Я не могу найти нужной библиотеки для работы с таблицами гугла. 
У меня есть ссылка на общедоступный(по ссылке) документ(excel таблица), он не мой и изменять его нельзя. 
Мне бы хотелось считывать данные с определенного диапазона и сохранять только их.
Доступ к таблице естественно только по ссылке.

gspread не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте к ссылке `export?format=csv'`.
Например, есть общедоступный документ https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VKjsb4sanastsb0Q5tIZiOjPbRpPa0t80ADBqxZAtfU/

Тогда ссылка для экспорта будет выглядеть так: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VKjsb4sanastsb0Q5tIZiOjPbRpPa0t80ADBqxZAtfU/export?format=csv

Теперь можно использовать ее в коде:

```
import csv
import io
import urllib.request


url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VKjsb4sanastsb0Q5tIZiOjPbRpPa0t80ADBqxZAtfU/export?format=csv'

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

with io.TextIOWrapper(response, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Результат:

```
['col1', 'col2', 'col3']    
['1', 'aa', '22df']
['5', 'cvcv', 'ere']
['3', 'rrr', 'rr442']
```

Или открыть с помощью [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VKjsb4sanastsb0Q5tIZiOjPbRpPa0t80ADBqxZAtfU/export?format=csv')
new_df = df[['col1', 'col2']]  # Выберем из датафрейма 2 столбца и сохраним в новый датафрейм
new_df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False) # Экспорт в CSV файл
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Это сработало, я очень благодарен.
Но в выводе у меня печатается полная неразбериха, что-то вроде этого : ['if(_.Y){var jj;if(jj=_.A(_.Y.f', '3))for(var kj=_.ch(jj)', 'lj=0;lj<kj.length;lj++)_.Ph(kj[lj]', 'ogpc', ');_.$i(_.Y', '!!_.Y.b&&_.Y.b.bc()', '!1)};']
['}catch(e){_._DumpException(e)}']
['try{']
['_.mj=funct

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Попробовал через pandas, это сработало! Вы мне очень помогли, но как я смог бы вывести для обработки больше "13 rows x 15 columns" и можно ли искать и выводить определенный столбец?
Вы можете также подсказать источники где я смог бы почитать про это на досуге, мне интересно разобраться в этом

Comment: код ровно копировал как у вас!

Comment: Затрудняюсь ответить почему вам куски кода в результате выдало. Что касается Pandas, то попробуйте поискать какие-нибудь обучающие статьи. Я сейчас дополню отзыв примером выбора только определенных столбцов.

Comment: Доброе утро, а вы можете пожалуйста подсказать, как я могу убрать индексы при выводе, если я не хочу экспортировать в csv, а хочу сделать из этого строку для вывода?
$new_df = df['Stack']

$new_df = str(new_df)

$result = new_df.replace('NaN', 'Нет')

$return result

Comment: И как можно обрезать конец вывода, то есть выбрать определенный лимит строк в столбце, такое возможно?

Comment: Для выбора определенного количества строк - метод `.loc()`. Для вывода в строку - `to_string()` с дополнительными параметрами. Это может выглядеть примерно так: `values = df.loc[:50, 'Stack'].to_string(index=False, header=False, na_rep='Нет')`. Этот код вернет строку из первых 50 значений без индексов, без имени столбца и с заменой NaN на 'Нет'. Значения будут разделены символом переноса строки, который можно заменить на пробел, например: `values = values.replace('\n', ' ')`