# Как считать данные с определенной ячейки Google Docs(Shields) при помощи Python(возможно использование библиотек csv, io, urllib.request)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-3.6, csv-helper

Вопрос по [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/934988/Как-я-могу-добыть-данные-с-google-docs-с-помощью-python/935009#935009](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/934988/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81-google-docs-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-python/935009#935009)

Добрый вечер добрые люди! Выше есть ссылка с кодом:

```
import csv
import io
import urllib.request
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VKjsb4sanastsb0Q5tIZiOjPbRpPa0t80ADBqxZAtfU/export?format=csv'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
with io.TextIOWrapper(response, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Тут, на сколько я понял, берется и целый файл переводится в двухмерный массив. Можно-ли как-то отредактировать/предложить свой вариант кода так чтобы вместе этого мы получали ответ на определенную ячейку. Например что-бы у нас были две переменные row, colomn. И если row=2, colomn=C, то выводилось 22df(ссылка на GoogleDocsTest:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VKjsb4sanastsb0Q5tIZiOjPbRpPa0t80ADBqxZAtfU/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать `Pandas`, но всё-равно сначала прочитается весь документ целиком:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VKjsb4sanastsb0Q5tIZiOjPbRpPa0t80ADBqxZAtfU/export?format=csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)
print(df.loc[0,'col3'])
```

Вывод:

```
22df
```

Только у вас это значение в строке `0` и колонке `col3`, вот вся таблица:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   1       aa      22df
1   5       cvcv    ere
2   3       rrr     rr442
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо

Comment: А у вас есть дискорд? Просто у меня есть пару вопросов которые я-бы хотел задать лично, буду премного благодарен

Comment: @Nik Я в дискорде ничего не понимаю. Другие мессенджеры есть, почта есть...

Comment: @Nik Нет, с таким не подскажу, тут `Pandas` уже не поможет