# Копирование данных из Google Sheets при помощи Python

Tags: python, pandas, google-spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

Мне необходимо создать программу которая сможет копировать и выводить в консоль значение запрошенной ячейки из Google Shields [сложной таблицы](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1evpX9QBS0cYSktPoInaSditbEcXaqmv1pear9nXb4hs/edit?usp=sharing).
Есть Код:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'link'
df = pd.read_csv(url)
print(df.loc[1:"col1"])
```

Но он способен достать информацию только из простой **.csv** таблицы, а это таблица уже не может быть форматом **.csv** так как она не может быть представлена в виде двухмерного массива. `pd.read_excel` вроде тоже не работает.

> А как теперь это сделать со сложной таблицей(см [пример](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1evpX9QBS0cYSktPoInaSditbEcXaqmv1pear9nXb4hs/edit?usp=sharing))?

**[ССЫЛКА НА МОЙ ВЧЕРАШНИЙ ВОПРОС](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1252149/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-google-docsshields-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-python)**

Comment: Зачем вам pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) для получения данных из Таблицы.

Самое простое для понимания - использование сервисного аккаунта.

### Создание сервисного аккаунта

1. Идете в консоль https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard
2. Создаете сервисный аккаунт
3. Запоминаете его email, типа "sa-my-title-000234@project-123.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
4. Выпускаете ключ
5. Сохраняете ключ в файл `creds.json`

### Скрипт

1. Заполняете `spreadsheet_id`
2. Заполняете `range_name`
3. Добавляете сервисный аккаунт соавтором или читателем вашей Таблицы
4. Запускаете

```
import httplib2
import os

from googleapiclient import discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

try:
    scopes = [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    ]
    secret_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "creds.json")

    spreadsheet_id = "1evpX9QBS0cYSktPoInaSditbEcXaqmv1pear9nXb4hs"
    range_name = "'расписание 2021'!B9"

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        secret_file, scopes=scopes
    )

    service = discovery.build("sheets", "v4", credentials=credentials)


    values=service.spreadsheets().values().get(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
        range=range_name,
    ).execute()

    print(values.get('values'))


except OSError as e:
    print(e)
```

### Вывод

В консоль выводится двумерный массив с размером 1x1 и единственным значением из ячейки `'расписание 2021'!B9` (ну, или что вы там напишете).

В данном случае

```sh
$> [['"Рисуем мир вокруг нас"\nАкимов М.\nАРТ-лаб']]
```

Comment: "from apiclient import discovery": ImportError: cannot import name 'discovery' from 'apiclient'

Comment: `from googleapiclient import discovery`, и если надо, то `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`

Comment: when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/x/values/Sheet2%21A1?alt=json returned "Unable to parse range: Sheet2!A1". Details: "Unable to parse range: Sheet2!A1">
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: @Nik, обновил ответ для вашей Таблицы

Comment: а не подскажите как смотреть другие листы таблицы:
```range_name = "'расписание 2020'!B9"```


Не работает :/

Comment: @Nik, для API вы определенно должны указать `range_name = "'расписание 2020'!B9"`. Я не понимаю, что значит "не работает". Оно возвращает ошибку или пустоту? Попробуйте указать ячейку, в которой точно есть данные `'расписание 2020'!A1`. Возможно, `B9` - часть объединенной ячейки.

Comment: Если в таблице идет две различные таблицы по одной ссылке, то есть возможность обратиться ко второй таблице? Код который я писал выше выдает "Unable to parse range: "6 классы"!B9". Details: "Unable to parse range: "6 классы"!В9"

Comment: Да, ошибка верная. Не `"6 классы"!B9"`, а `"'6 классы'!B9"`.

Comment: Still isnt working :/

Comment: Так не пойдет. Мы ж не приложение дебажим. Нужна точечная поддержка - напишите в личку. Я уверен, что проблема в имени диапазона.

Comment: напишу все полностью подробно в новом вопросе и скину вам ссылку

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1257573/google-sheets-api-error-unable-to-parse-range