# Google Sheets API error "Unable to parse range"

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

Есть код:

```
import httplib2
import os
from googleapiclient import discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

day_transform=[["B","F","I","M","P"],["B","F","I","K","N"],["B","E","H","K","N"],["B","D","G","J","M"],["B","E","H","K","M"],["B","E","H","K","N"],["B","D","","","O"]]
def get_info(grd,day,time):
    colomn="A"
    row=1
    scopes = [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    ]
    secret_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "creds.json")
    spreadsheet_id = "x"
    range_name = "'"+str(grd)+" классы'!"+colomn+row
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        secret_file, scopes=scopes
    )
    service = discovery.build("sheets", "v4", credentials=credentials)
    values=service.spreadsheets().values().get(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
        range=range_name,
    ).execute()
    print(values.get('values'))

get_info(5,1,1)
```

Есть ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 24, in <module>
    get_info(5,1,1)
  File "main.py", line 21, in get_info
    values=service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,range=range_name,).execute()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 920, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/x/values/%275%20%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%27%21A1?alt=json returned "Unable to parse range: '5 классы'!A1". Details: "Unable to parse range: '5 классы'!A1">
```

Причем я уверен что ссылка содержит таблицу с названием `<5 классы>`. в другой вкладке (таблица 1 называется `<расписание 2021>`, вкладка 2 называется `<5 классы>`). Как исправить?

Comment: у вас в range_name - строка со значением 5 классы'!A1 и вы задаете ее в качестве range для service.spreadsheets().values().get()... так задумано?

Comment: Код скопирован, но на сколько я понимаю, так и должно быть

Comment: range в таблицах задается как-то так: А1:F13

Comment: @Jack_Os Необходимо указывать название таблицы

Comment: Пришлите ссылку на Таблицу

Comment: ничего не поменялось